# Deploying django project with Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a django project with Apache but I got this error

```
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:27.321603 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1308] [client ::1:7844] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'\r
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:40.381358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1304] [client ::1:7852] mod_wsgi (pid=11440): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/htdocs/project/djangoProject/djangoProject/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:40.381358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1304] [client ::1:7852] mod_wsgi (pid=11440): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/htdocs/project/djangoProject/djangoProject/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:40.381358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1304] [client ::1:7852] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:40.381358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1304] [client ::1:7852]   File "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/htdocs/project/djangoProject/djangoProject/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>\r
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:40.381358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1304] [client ::1:7852]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Tue Oct 23 11:05:40.381358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11440:tid 1304] [client ::1:7852] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'\r
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if I could but my reputation isn't high enough. Have you tried installing the django module using `pip` on the server? Also are you using a virtualenv or are your installations for the project system wide? It's advised that you use a virtualenv rather, it's easy to set up and is also widely supported in terms of advice from other developers. Here's a [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) to a page that set me on the right path. Though I notice you're using windows, you could get a rough idea from this.